# How to start with clingo?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo, gringo

I have install clingo. But I don't know how to run it. There are some examples in the file. I tried to run it. But it failed.

I installed it in both windows and Ubuntu. And I have add it to the path.

> C:\Windows\system32>clingo color.lp\graph.lp clingo version 5.3.0
>   Reading from color\graph : error: file could not be opened:
>   color.lp\graph
>
> C:\Windows\system32> clingo context-py.lp encoding.lp --of=3 0
>   *** ERROR: (clingo): 'encoding': could not open input file!
>   *** Info : (clingo): Try '--help' for usage information
>
> C:\Windows\system32> clingo context-lua.lp encoding.lp --of=3 0
>   *** ERROR: (clingo):  could not open input file!
>   *** Info : (clingo): Try '--help' for usage information

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is simply that you are trying to run the files from the wrong directory.
I assume your example files are not in your windows system 32 directory.
You need to navigate to the correct directory where the .lp files are located, then you can run Clingo.